# How do I show density in Sobolev Space?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I'm confused on how to prove this:

$C^{\infty}(\mathbf{R}^n)\cap H^s$ is dense in $H^s=L^{2}_{s}$.

Comment: Is $H^s=H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @Jose27 yes, it is

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried mollification?

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I thought of using the Sobolev embedding theorem but I'm not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: The Sobolev embedding theorem are good to "trade" the smoothness component $s$ for a hight exponent of integrability $2 \leq p$ instead of $2$. You don't want that. What i was sugesting: pick a normalized gaussian $\gamma_t$ of mean $0$ and $\sigma = t$. $\gamma \ast f$ is $C^\infty$. Next show that $\gamma_t \ast f \to f$ in the $L_s^2$ norm.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez I don't quite follow